# finitely repeated prisoner§s dilemma

Tags: game-theory

In the finite repeated prisoner's dilemma the strategy for both always cheat the other prisoner is a sub-game perfect equilibrium. Is there any other Nash equlibrium (note necessarily subgame perfect) besides this ? I think that one other is always cooperate with the other prisoner. Any else ?

Comment: If the other prisoner does not cheat you,, ¿what is your best response?

Comment: I which round ? Remember that the game is T stage.

Comment: The last stage.

Comment: @FOE To cheat him. What next to consider ?

Comment: Therefore if there exists a Nash equilibrium, in the last stage both should cheat. Therefore we should search for the equilibrium in the set of strategies such that in the last game both players cheat. I think we could deduce that in such subset both players should cheat in the stage T-1

Comment: @FOE So the only NE is always cheat as is the SPE ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133888/discussion-between-foe-and-user122424).